# Why security permissions 777 on the attachments Magento directory are ( are not ) safe?

Tags: magento-1.9

What is preventing a hacker from deleting or even worse uploading a file to the 777 attachments folder ?

Specifically how to ensure that the server host is actually restricting that ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about server settings and security. There are several stackexchange sites that will probably get you better answers

Comment: This question is not off topic. It is about the configuration of the Magento attachments folder. I edited the title to clarify it.

Comment: When referencing directories in Magento, please supply the full path from Magento root. "attachments Magento directory" is kind of nebulous as a description. DYM `media/downloadable/`? Also, version would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

We recommend against 777 permissions on the Magento file system. Here is one way you can set permissions (consult your network admin; there could be other ways as well): http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

Let us know if you need more information.